# Making an UnorderedVector from an UnorderedListADT, but getting an unchecked cast error

Tags: java, list, data-structures, unordered, unchecked-cast

I'm very confused at the moment when dealing with this concept of casting objects and whatnot, but I believe I am very close to being finished. If you could please take a look at my code and clue me in on what I could do to stop receiving this error, it'd be great.

```
public E remove(int position){
    position -= 1;
    if(outOfBounds(position))
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid position.");
    E[] temp;
    temp = (E[])storage[position];// around here is where I receive the error
    currentSize--;
    shiftLeft(position);
    return temp[position];
}// DONE
```

Here is my second attempt after the first reply's suggestion(however, still receiving an unchecked cast error):

```
public E remove(int position){
    position -= 1;
    if(outOfBounds(position))
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid position.");
    E[]temp = (E[])new Object[maxSize];
    temp = (E[])storage[position];
    currentSize--;
    shiftLeft(position);
    return temp[position];}// DONE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the definition of "storage," but I assume that it is an array. You can't cast an array of one type to an array of another type. You can only cast Array to a superclass, such as Object.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I will try to see what I can do to solve this with your feedback.

Comment: Hello, I changed some code and was hoping you could take a look at it, I made a new Object of generic type array named temp